# What does the word "veritable" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Vocabulary.com defines the above word as follows:

- "When something is veritable it is true, or at least feels that way.
  "The trees and lights turned the campus into a veritable wonderland"
  means that the campus seemed to be transformed into a true wonderland
  (if there is such a thing).

  Veritable comes from the Latin veritas which means true. But unlike
  true, it does not describe things like statements. It is often used
  to enhance the word that follows it. "A veritable cornucopia of food"
  is a lot of food of different varieties. If someone calls you "a
  veritable force of nature," they don't mean that you are actually a
  hurricane; they just mean that you have the unstoppable quality of a
  big old storm."

I'm still not sure what this word actually means. Does it mean "having the appearance/semblance of being genuine or true"?

Comment: Try dictionaries also, like Collins, Cambridge, Oxford Leaners, Macmillan. You can use Google by adding 'meaning' after the word you are curious about.

Comment: Normally, questions asking for definitions of words are off-topic for this site, since anyone should be able to look up the answer in a dictionary. However, in this case, even comprehensive and reputable dictionaries fail to fully explain this usage, as I have pointed out in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Although 'veritable' originally meant 'actually true', we use it in modern times to emphasise a metaphor or figurative expression. If I say that my father is a veritable tiger when he is angry, I do not mean that when he is angry he truly, literally, becomes a tiger complete with stripes, claws, whiskers, etc. I mean that 'tiger' is a very apt metaphor (because he is fierce).

> veritable adjective [ before noun ]
>
> used to describe something as another, more
> exciting, interesting, or unusual thing, as a way of emphasizing its
> character:
>
> *My garden had become a veritable jungle by the time I came
> back from holiday.*
>
> *The normally sober menswear department is set to
> become a veritable kaleidoscope of colour this season.*

[Veritable (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/veritable)

Answer (score 0):

English has repeatedly turned words meaning "true" into an **intensifier**.

The obvious example is [*very*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/very), which is the most common and generic intensifier:

> #### very (adj.)
>
> late 13c., *verray* "true, real, genuine," later "actual, sheer" (late 14c.), from Anglo-French *verrai*, Old French *verai* "true, truthful, sincere; right, just, legal," from Vulgar Latin **veracus*, from Latin *verax* (genitive veracis) "truthful," from *verus* "true" (source also of Italian *vero*), from PIE root **were-o-* "true, trustworthy." Meaning "greatly, extremely" is first recorded mid-15c. Used as a pure intensive since Middle English.

You can see other examples of phenomenon, such as *truly* (as in "that was a truly amazing performance!") and *really*.

The same thing is happening with *veritable* in your example, except that here it is intensifying a noun rather than an adjective.  Even reputable dictionaries will define *veritable* as "true" without explaining the extended usage as an intensifier.  For example, even the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00276425) only barely hints at this usage:

> #### veritable, *adj.* (and *adv.*)
>
> **1.**
>
> **a.** Of a statement, etc.: That is in accordance or conformity with the truth or verity; true. ? *Obsolete.*
>
> **†b.** Of persons: Speaking the truth; truthful, veracious. *Obsolete.*
>
> **2.**
>
> **a.** Genuine, real, true; not counterfeit, false, or spurious; correctly or properly so called.
>
> **b.** Of things or persons.
>  ︙
>  1881 *Lit. World* 21 Jan. 37/1 Nelson, we all know, was a veritable sea king.
>
> **c.** With *the*, in emphatic use.
>
> **3.** In extended use, denoting possession of all the distinctive qualities of the person or thing specified.
>
> **†4.** As adv. Veritably, truly. *Obsolete. rare.*

(I'm quoting from the paywalled June 2022 online entry, but linking to the publicly viewable 1989 OED2; the two are substantially similar.)

However, the use of *veritable* as an intensifier is still attested elsewhere.  For example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Intensifier&oldid=1093643920#Examples_of_English_intensifiers) also lists *veritable* as an example of an intensifier.  Also, [The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English](https://www.encyclopedia.com/humanities/dictionaries-thesauruses-pictures-and-press-releases/veritable) says:

> **ver·i·ta·ble** /ˈvəritəbəl/
>
> - adj. used as an intensifier, often to qualify a metaphor: *the early 1970s witnessed a veritable price explosion.*